# multinote instruments and chords

Tags: ableton-live

I am new in ableton live software. I would like to understand why for some instruments I can play several notes at the same time (and create chord progression) and for the others I can hear only one note of a chord. 
For example, there are two guitars: 'Power Chords Guitar' and 'Please Rise For Jimi Guitar'. Both of them are basing on an operator. For the first one I am able to press several buttons on midi keyboard and hear a sound, for the second I can hear only one note of a chord.
I was trying to compare operator options, but I was unable to find the setting which causes this multinote/mononote functionality.
Thank you very much for your help.
J

Answer (score 0):

Ableton's Operator consists of 4 monophonic oscillators. Depending on a preset, it can be setup to play polyphony. It seems that the *Glide* function is responsible for that effect. Make sure you have at least 2 oscillators (the more the more poly) with *Glide* "on" set.

Check out Ableton's [webpage](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/live-instrument-reference/) for reference on how to use its instruments.